# How to fix: faulting application w3wp.exe?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, iis

In the Event Viewer:

```
Source: Application Error
Category: 100
Event ID: 1000

Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, fault address 0x000000000000dd50.
```

This error is happening on my background-app server (not web server).  It's happening every 3-5 minutes.

What's the problem in laymen's terms?  And then the solution? :)

Or if this isn't enough info, how can I troubleshoot?

Comment: We (you) need to know what's running in that application pool (the w3wp is the worker process for IIS appliation pools).  Are there any customer ISAPI filters, .Net apps, CGI?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in IIS admin, look at the web sites and app pools.

What I would do is stop a web site for 20 mins, see if that stops the faulting. Once you identify the problem web site, see if the iis logs or web application error logs or eventvwr can give you more info.